# vueuse useDark function blocking the ability to transition an element

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, vueuse

Hey I have been troubleshooting this for a while but can't seem to figure it out. To give some context I am creating a dark mode for my site and I am using useDark from the vueuse library which is referenced here: [useDark](https://vueuse.org/core/useDark/#usedark)

essentially it checks localStorage then user preferences to find whether they prefer light or dark mode. it then provides a boolean ref that we can use to do whatever. also it applies the class `dark` to the html documentElement `<html class="dark">`.

so whats the problem, well i am using tailwindcss to create a toggle button that allows the user to switch between light and dark.

here is a stackblitz example: [using ref not useDark](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-zpbeof?file=src%2FApp.vue)

code reference:

```js
<script setup>
import { useDark, useToggle } from '@vueuse/core';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const isDark = ref(true);
// const isDark = useDark();
const toggleDark = useToggle(isDark);
</script>

<template>
  <button
    class="h-8 w-16 pl-1 rounded-full bg-slate-300"
    type="button"
    @click="toggleDark()"
  >
    <div
      class="h-7 w-7 rounded-full bg-slate-400 transition-all"
      :class="{ 'translate-x-7': isDark }"
    />
  </button>
</template>
```

this essentially does nothing when using a ref and that is intentional to show that the transition of that toggle works fine

the problem i am having is if you comment out the ref and use useDark ref instead there is no smooth transition. I have troubleshooted so much to get to this point and I am absolutely lost as to why.

one thing you can do to force it to work is adding!transition-all to the inner div giving it importance but I dont know if this is the correct fix or if i just worked around it. What I am looking for is why this is happening

I have tried adding the dark class to the documentElement but using only a ref and it seemed to work as well but then I would not be using useDark and also would need to manage my own localStorage and use preferences lookup.

also i have done it using raw css and i get the same incorrect behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging and creating an issue in the vueuse repo the solution was found below with an explanation.

https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse/issues/3233

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a watch to watch the state of prefrence of user. It's a good idea to implement a watch to track the user's preference. By doing this, you can control the timing and order of operations when the preference changes, which will help address the issue with the transition not occurring smoothly.

Here's an example of how you might update your script:

```
<script setup>
import { useDark, useToggle } from '@vueuse/core';
import { watch } from 'vue';

const isDark = useDark();

const toggleDark = useToggle(isDark);

// watch the isDark ref to manage transitions
watch(isDark, (newVal) => {
  // toggle the 'dark' class on the documentElement after a delay
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.documentElement.classList.toggle('dark', newVal);
  }, 150);  
});
</script>

<template>
  <button
    class="h-8 w-16 pl-1 rounded-full bg-slate-300"
    type="button"
    @click="toggleDark()"
  >
    <div
      class="h-7 w-7 rounded-full bg-slate-400 transition-all"
      :class="{ 'translate-x-7': isDark }"
    />
  </button>
</template>
```

When isDark changes (i.e., when the user toggles the button), it triggers a function that waits for a short delay before toggling the 'dark' class on the document. This delay ensures that the transition classes have been applied before the 'dark' class is toggled, creating a smooth transition effect.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Ali thanks for the help but this defeats the purpose of useDark since it should be handling what happens when toggled. Also, this wouldn't work as we expect since we are still allowing useDark to toggle the class in its function side effects but then we toggle it again in the watch. For this to work we would ditch useDark entirely and just use a ref which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Dear puwya it is a utility to be added to your project. So you need to handle it on your own. There, a watch needed to implement the toggle. I don't know any other workaround, so if any, please add as answer here.

Comment: Hey Ali, well I kinda get what you are saying but useDark already handles adding the dark class to documentElement so it wouldn't make sense for me to handle that. If I find the answer I will post.