# vuejs transition animation get stopped get toggling dark mode

Tags: vue.js

I have an `App.vue` that imports a custom component called `DarkSwitch.vue`. The darkswitch adds a `.dark` class to the html element, however when that happens the transition for the switch gets cut off. I can get this to work with a workaround where I use `watch` rather then `computed`.

```
const isDarkClass = ref("");

watch(isDark, async () => {
  await nextTick();
  isDarkClass.value = isDark.value ? "translate-x-5" : "translate-x-0";
});
```

What I have now

```
<script setup>
import { useDark, useToggle } from "@vueuse/core";
import { computed } from "vue";

let isDark = useDark();
const toggleDark = useToggle(isDark);

const isDarkClass = computed(() => {
  return isDark.value ? "translate-x-5" : "translate-x-0";
});
</script>

<template>
  <button
    type="button"
    class="relative inline-flex h-6 w-11 flex-shrink-0 cursor-pointer rounded-full border-2 border-transparent bg-purple transition-colors duration-200 ease-in-out focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-600 focus:ring-offset-2 dark:bg-green"
    role="switch"
    @click="toggleDark()"
  >
    <span
      aria-hidden="true"
      class="pointer-events-none inline-block h-5 w-5 transform rounded-full bg-white shadow ring-0 transition duration-200 ease-in-out"
      :class="isDarkClass"
    ></span>
  </button>
</template>
```

I am confused why the css transtions won't work.

Comment: Does using `translate-x-0 dark:translate-x-5` in your class definition for your span work? Then you won't need the extra dynamic class.

Comment: @Yitz Thanks for the comment, no it doensn't work.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76696520/8170844) answer and the linked GitHub issue.

Comment: Yup that seems to have worked. Thanks a lot!